# Total of LOOKUP function in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

For each group in SSRS (Countries, cities...) I calculate sales divided by exchange rates:

```
Sum(Fields!Net_Sales_Amount.Value)/LOOKUP(Fields!Country.Value, Fields!Country.Value, Fields!RATE.Value, "Currency")
```

How I can create Total of this sum (sum for last group - countries)?

Each solution that I found show how to do it only for alone LOOKUP function. I need to divide field by it.

Here is layout of my report:

[image]

and structure:

[image]

To calculate sales for country I just need to sum sales and divide it by LOOKUP function, but I couldn't do it for Total. I need to some below values.

Comment: Do you want to total each `sum(sales)/lookup(value)` or do you want to divide the total of `sum(sales)` by the total of all `lookup(values)`?

Comment: I need to divide each sales before sum (I have one, different value for each country)

Comment: Please add an actual screenshot of your report and not a recreation of it in excel...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you just need to change which data you are summing together, as it looks like you are simply finding exchange rates?

If this is the case, you should be able to just use

```
=Sum(Fields!Net_Sales_Amount.Value/LOOKUP(Fields!Country.Value, Fields!Country.Value, Fields!RATE.Value, "Currency"))
```

in your total textbox, which needs to be outside the group you are using to show the individual values.

---

If you want to lookup a lot of values and then `sum` them all together however, this is a little more complex.

Rather than using `lookup`, you will need to use `lookupset`, which uses the same syntax but can return more than one value.  There is, however, no built in function that can `sum` these returned values up, as the values that get returned in the `lookupset` function are actually objects rather than numbers.  As such, you will need to use custom code.

Open up your Report Properties and then the Custom Code window, into which you can paste the following:

```
Function SumLookup(ByVal items As Object()) As Decimal
If items Is Nothing Then
  Return Nothing
End If

Dim suma As Decimal = New Decimal()
Dim ct as Integer = New Integer()
suma = 0
ct = 0

For Each item As Object In items
  suma += Convert.ToDecimal(item)
  ct += 1
Next

If (ct = 0) Then return 0 else return suma 
End Function
```

This can then be used in a textbox as an expression:

```
=Code.SumLookup(LookupSet(Fields!Country.Value, Fields!Country.Value, Fields!RATE.Value, "Currency"))
```

which you can use alongside other numeric values for aggregations or calculations.

Comment: Yes, I simply looking for exchange rates for each sales. First approach returns me NAN value even If I convert NULLs to 0 (using custom function).

Comment: @Testtest11  Do you have any `NULL` values in your datasets?  Also, why aren't you including your exchange rates in your `Sales` dataset and doing this calculation before the data gets to your report?

Comment: I get correct values for groups. I have NaN only for total. This is different exchange rates used for budget planning (one exchange rate for country/currency). I take data from OLAP cube and do LOOKUP because I didn't find better solution.

Comment: @Testtest11  You are going to need to add some screenshots of your report design to your question in order to get more detailed and specific help.